# Is the iPhone NSOperationQueue implementation bugged?

Tags: iphone, multithreading, macos

In MacOS Leopard versions prior to 10.5.7, `NSOperationQueue` was [famously buggy](http://www.mikeash.com/?page=pyblog/dont-use-nsoperationqueue.html).

Does anyone know if this bug applies to the iPhone OS (which also features this API),
and if so to which versions?

Comment: You might want to read the comments on that post.

Comment: Like "I suspect that the iPhone may be immune" and "Hopefully it doesn't affect ARM"? I was hoping for something a little more concrete, even if negative, e.g. yes, it crashes in 2.x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't effect the iPhone as far as anyone can tell. No one ever got it to reproduce on an iPhone. Some people got it to run in a simulator, but the simulator uses the system frameworks so that is not surprising.

No one knows why did not repro on the phone, whether because it was fixed indepeendtly in iPhone OS, or if being single processor or ARM prevented it.

Also, iPhone is not Leopard based, it is an independent build train made from many of the same components as Mac OS X, but they don't have to wait until something is in the desktop release to pull it in. A number of the frameworks in the current iPhone OS 3.0 release are based on what will ship in Snow Leopard.

Comment: I said "derivative", but point taken, OP edited. Who knows? Even though 2.x "feels" like Leopard, they may have written the whole thing from scratch.